# CONDITIONAL FORMATTING - Unable to format column

Tags: json-formatting, column-formatting, conditional

I have a SharePoint LIST that's being used to manage events. There are 6 participants for each event and each Participant has a column:

"Participant 1", "Participant 2", "Participant 3", "Participant 4", "Participant 5", "Participant 6"

I need the FILL color of Participant 1-3 to be Green if EMPTY and Transparent if NOT EMPTY
I need the FILL color of Participant 4-6 to be YELLOW if EMPTY and Transparent if NOT EMPTY

I have been able to accomplish the above - my issue is that the "[$Evenement]" column has two choices; Orientation/Formation. If the selected choice is Orientation - I need the Participant 4/5 columns to have GREEN fill IF EMPTY and Transparent if NOT EMPTY. Below is the code that's not working for what I need. Any help would be appreciated - I am a complete newbie to JSON.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField == '', '#98FB98', if(@currentField == 'blocked', '#FF6A6A', if([$Evenement] == 'Orientation', '#FFFF66', '')))"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. You just need nest one `if()` inside the other like so:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if([$Evenement] == 'Orientation', if(@currentField == '', 'green', 'transparent'), 'transparent')"
  }
}
```

[image]

**Update. Final code version**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "debugMode": true,
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField == '', if([$Evenement] == 'Formation', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-greenLight', if([$Evenement] == 'Orientation','ms-bgColor-sharedYellow10', if(@currentField == 'blocked', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-errorBackground50','transparent'))) ,if(@currentField == 'blocked', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-errorBackground50', '') )"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your code and I had tried that myself before but this is what happens: https://imgur.com/a/s4tfYwX

Comment: I think I misunderstood your conditions. I've updated the code in the answer. Can you try the new version?

Comment: Denis, you have no idea how much I appreciate your help - you've brought me half way through!!! thank you!!! I am trying to add two additional conditions in there - 1. IF text is "blocked" change the FILL to RED and 2. IF Evenement is "Formation" then it should be a different FILL like lets say yellow.

Comment: @UmarShehzad, nice. Can you please accept the answer? if it helped you.

Comment: I am trying to write the nested IF's like Excel but the logic doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @Denismolodtsov, can you please tell me how can I further add conditions into this code the way I mentioned?

Comment: Can you list all conditions in one place? Arrange them in order of importance. I.e., what if two conditions collide, which is more important? To be honest, it's hard to decypher this information from your question.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/biDUtVK here you go!

Comment: Okey, that was useful. Updated the answer. Please accept if it helped you.

Comment: Thank you very much Denis! Not only you`ve helped me tremendously but you`ve enabled me to understand this enough to be able to modify it and even add icons with conditions :) Thanks again!